# React JS template, config.json keep on minifying

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

In my project I'm using the Microsoft React Redux Template ([Microsoft React](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react-with-redux?view=aspnetcore-5.0)) with typescript. My problem is I need to keep set of frontend configurations like API base URL ect. I've used a Config.Json file. But when the project is build, every javascript file that referenced the Config.Json file get referenced and copied the content of the .Json file, at the minifying process. So I have to manually go through the each minified .js file and change the configurations when moving from Dev to QA or QA to Prod.

I tried to keep the configurations in a JS file, but still same problem occurs.

Is there a way to stop referencing the Config.Json file at JS minifying process. So that when I change the Config.Json file, the changes of the configurations will get applied.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use environment variables.

`npm i dotenv -D`

```js
import configTest from 'config.test.json';
import configProd from 'config.prod.json';

const config = process.env.BUILD_TARGET === 'prod' ? configProd : configTest;
```